# How to protect against automated scans and calls of non-exported activities

Tags: android, android-intent

My company has some android apps on Google Play that are occasionally targeted by malicious automated tools that scan and launch all activities in the apps.  (I was able to detect these scans because they generate a lot of crash reports.)  What I find most worrisome about these scans is that they are able to make explicit intent calls to non-exported activities.  That is, they are calling activities have the `exported` attribute set to `false` and don't have `<intent-filter>`s.

Are there any additional steps I can take to prevent non-exported activities from being invoked outside my app?  Are there any other security measures that I should take?

One other interesting tidbit about these scans.  They all seem to be run from an emulator.  Perhaps they have some mechanism to make the intents look like they are coming from inside my app.  If this is the case, is there some way I can protect against that?

Comment: "What I find most worrisome about these scans is that they are able to make explicit intent calls to non-exported activities" -- what is your evidence of this?

Comment: what do you risk with these scans?

Comment: Our applications include a library that has activities not used by those particular apps.  I am getting crash reports from those unused activities, even though those activities are not exported and have no intent filters.  They are crashing due to NPEs because those activities expect certain intent extras to be set but aren't.  I suspect it is due to a hacking tool since I see about two dozen of these NPEs from all the activities in the library within seconds of each other in roughly alphabetical order of their package names.

Comment: @lelloman, As for what I risk, not too much.  Most of our apps require a login and our activities don't work without a properly initialized login context.  You will get kicked back to the login screen if it is not properly initialized  I also took the precaution to encrypt all shared preferences.  But given that we write apps aimed at enterprise customers, I want to ensure that our apps are as secure as possible.

Comment: I was just curious, anyway I read in the documentation that exported set to false means that you can still launch an activity from outside the app if you know the class name. Did yout try to set [permission attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#prmsn)?